# Shared dropout layer on input

Tags: keras, dropout

I want to apply same dropout to two input tensors of same shape. One way to do that is to join the inputs, apply dropout and then split the tensors again. This way same features will get dropped from each input in each iteration.

The code seems to work fine and model is training. Can anyone confirm that what i have done is doing what i am expecting? I don't know of a way to compare tensors or else i could just change dropout to 0 and compare the output with input.

```
#input1 (10, 6) input2 (10,6)
input_list = [input1, input2]

#Join inputs and form (20x6) tensor
input_concat = keras.layers.concatenate(input_list, axis=1)
input_dropout = Dropout(0.5)(input_concat)
reshaped_input = keras.layers.Reshape((10, 6, 2))(input_dropout)

input_1 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[:,:,:,0])(reshaped_input)
input_2 = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[:,:,:,1])(reshaped_input)
```